# Laravel Telescope - Log only errors status in Requests panel

Tags: laravel, laravel-telescope

In Laravel Telescope debug tool, in the "Requests" panel, is there a way to only log some requests, and not all requests ?

For instance, all requests except those with `200` or `302` status.

I tried to modify `config/telescope.php` file, especially that part

```
Watchers\RequestWatcher::class => [
    'enabled' => env('TELESCOPE_REQUEST_WATCHER', true),
    'size_limit' => env('TELESCOPE_RESPONSE_SIZE_LIMIT', 64),
]
```

But i didn't find any options about page status.

And I also tried modifying the `TelescopeServiceProvider.php` file, the `register()` method but without success.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telescope allows you to search entries by "tag". Often, tags are Eloquent model class names or authenticated user IDs which Telescope automatically adds to entries. Occasionally, you may want to attach your own custom tags to entries. To accomplish this, you may use the `Telescope::tag` method. The tag method accepts a closure which should return an array of tags. The `tags` returned by the closure will be merged with any tags Telescope would automatically attach to the entry. Typically, you should call the `tag` method within the `register` method of your `App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider` class:

```
use Laravel\Telescope\IncomingEntry;
use Laravel\Telescope\Telescope;

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->hideSensitiveRequestDetails();

    Telescope::tag(function (IncomingEntry $entry) {
        return $entry->type == 'request' && $entry->content['response_status'] == 302) ;
    });
 }
```

You can also do the same with the `filter` method instead of tag.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @MrEduar, I was able to do it this way :

```
Telescope::filter(function (IncomingEntry $entry) {
    if($entry->type == 'request' && !in_array($entry->content['response_status'], [200, 302])){
        return true;
    }else {
        return $entry->isReportableException() ||
            $entry->isFailedRequest() ||
            $entry->isFailedJob() ||
            $entry->isScheduledTask() ||
            $entry->hasMonitoredTag();
    }
});
```